# DB2 Trigger Explanation

Tags: sql, triggers, db2

Hey so i'm learning about triggers in DB2. And i missed the class where we went over it but i have a sample problem to do to understand it:

create a trigger program that will fire and total the item values (QTY * COST/PRICE) when any item record is added, changed or deleted and resulting value total in your order file.

My table name is "Items" and the columns are [Ordernum, Itemnum, ItemDesc, QTYORD, Date, Cost]

Could someone explain how you go about doing this? I tried looking here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000931.html  but i was a little confusing....

I know you are supposed to do:

CREATE TRIGGER Total_Item_Values 
   AFTER UPDATE ON ITEMS
   FOR EACH ROW

But after that i'm lost.

Comment: While this may be good practice for a trigger, this would be a **TERRIBLE** thing to do to a production, transactional, system.  Otherwise, what (more specifically) are you having trouble with?  You should be able to place a normal update statement after what you have there.

Answer (score 1):

I actually ended up getting it. Here is how part of it looks like.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Total_Item_Values 
   AFTER UPDATE ON ITEMS 
   REFERENCING NEW AS N
   FOR EACH ROW
   MODE DB2ROW

BEGIN ATOMIC
   UPDATE ORDER
   SET DOLLARS = (SELECT SUM(COST*QTYORD) 
   FROM ITEMS I WHERE N.ORDERNUM = I.ORDERNUM
   GROUP BY I.ORDERNUM)
WHERE N.ORDERNUM = O.ORDERNUM;
    END;
```